# How to reshape Quanteda corpus by values of a docvar?

Tags: r, reshape, quanteda

I'm working with a text corpus in R using the quanteda package. Suppose this corpus contains some texts that are split into sentences. Using `corpus_reshape()` it is easy enough, in theory, to switch between sentences and actual documents as unit of analysis. However, what if I want to reshape my corpus depending on the values of a specific variable in my `docvars`?

```
# Load quanteda

library(quanteda)

Package version: 3.3.1
Unicode version: 13.0
ICU version: 69.1
Parallel computing: 8 of 8 threads used.

# Create a simulated corpus
texts <- c(
  "Document one text. It has several sentences. Here is another sentence.",
  "Document two is slightly longer. It has more sentences. This is the third sentence. And here is the fourth."
)

# Create dummy across documents
docvars <- data.frame(dummy_var = c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1))

# Create the corpus
my_corpus <- corpus(texts) %>% corpus_reshape(to = "sentences")

# Define docvars
docvars(my_corpus) <- docvars

# Reshape to document parts based on dummy_var?
...
```

The desired output would be a new corpus where each document is split into two parts based on the dummy variable, resulting in a total of 4 documents in this case.

Could someone suggest an efficient way to do this in quanteda?

My idea is to split the documents into "halves" > tokenize > dfm to prepare them for scaling (e.g. wordfish), to see if the group the sentences fall into makes any difference. Specifically, my question is: Is there more left-right variance when it comes to `dummy_var == 0` than `dummy_var == 1`?

Please let me know if there're any flaws in that approach.

Answer (score 0):

I **think** I found a solution to my problem using a combination of tidyverse and quanteda. Here's what it looks like:

```
library(tidyverse)

docvars(my_corpus) <- docvars(my_corpus) %>%
  mutate(index = paste0(docid(my_corpus), "_", dummy_var))

corpus_group(my_corpus, index)
```

Still not entirely sure, however, if my approach is correct all in all.

Comment: Yes, you want `corpus_group()`. See also https://github.com/quanteda/quanteda.tidy for easier `mutate` operations.

Comment: Thanks Ken. That's interesting. If I understand this correctly, `quanteda.tidy` essentially renders the `docvars()` function unneccessary and I can do: `my_corpus %>% mutate()`. Right?

Comment: Correct. It provides access to tidyverse functions that operate directly on the docvars.